# how save data oneSignal react-native

Tags: react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

how can i save my push history on my device? I'm developing on react-native, when the event is open, I can save only the last push, and I need to store everything on the device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about navigation push history, you can make use of Redux, create a navigation store with [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), then use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save it to the device memory through AsyncStorage. Obviously, no need to mention that you have to dispatch it when navigating.

Comment: Hello, no, I didn’t mean that, what I wanted is described in this documentation, I learned the solution from technical support, thanks https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/create-an-activity-feed